# More line-efficient way to use re.search to match string in a list?

Tags: python

I did some light searching but didn't come up with anything solid - totally willing to delete this if it is a duplicate.

I'm trying to understand lambda functions better, and I'm pretty sure I can use them to reduce the for loop in:

```
import re
leest = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

x = ""
for i in leest:
    if re.search("th.*e", i):
        x = i

print "yay " + x + "!"
```

Whereby all I want is to pull out the matching term and use it in the function.

I've been looking at list comprehension and map, but that appears to be for accomplishing work such as adding items to lists or processing them.

Comment: Lambdas don't make code more efficient. `break`ing once you find a match would make it more efficient, though.

Comment: Good call - I adjusted the title of the question, I'm looking for a less-messy-looking solution, not necessarily processing efficiency.

Comment: Do you want to deal with the first entry matched, the last entry matched, or all entries matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `next` and a generator expression:

```
x = next(s for s in leest if re.search("th.*e", s))
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if it doesn't find a match. If you want to default to `""`, you can pass a default to `next`:

```
x = next((s for s in leest if re.search("th.*e", s)), "")
```

Comment: And if you want all matches, you can use a list comprehension. If you want the last match (as in your example), you can use `reversed(leest)`.

Comment: Is the "i" in your example supposed to be s?

Comment: @Locane: Indeed it is.